# String to Array via expressions

Tags: azure-logic-apps

How do I convert a string to an array:

```
"[\"123.123.123.123\",\"123.123.123.123\"]"
```

Let's say you have a string like above, how do I convert it to an array via expressions or a module. It comes from a request like below.

```
{
    "headers": {
        "ip": "[\"123.123.123.123\",\"123.123.123.123"]"
    }
}
```

here is my workflow:
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Any reason why you've escaped all of the quotes?  If it's coming from another payload, that's just a string, you need to remove them all for your scenario as it won't come through like that and my answer will work for you.  If you provide more context then I can adjust my answer but for now, I've made the assumption I have.

Comment: yes its coming from another payload. i couldnt figure out how to remove the quotes and slashes. that's why i posted the question. i understand your solution but it doesnt show me how to get rid of the slashes or quotes

Comment: You shouldn’t need to, it's just a string, it's escaping the quotes because they're in the value of the property within the JSON, show us that payload and I’ll show you what to do.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the body of the json im receiving.

Comment: Screenshots are never good but thanks

Comment: Back to you now, answer updated.

Comment: added my workflow for context, and the json as text in the post

Comment: Cool, my answer stands.  Just pass the resulting `Parse JSON` dynamic value for the `ip` into the JSON function like I've provided.  I've given you enough to be able to make your flow work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to extract the value of your IP address string from the headers of your HTTP call/trigger.

I can't help you with the exact answer because I don't know the name of the action that's giving you that result but, using the same approach to `Initialise` a variable, you can get the string.

So something like ...

```
outputs('HTTP')['headers']['ip']
```

Then, use the `json` function over the top of that value ...

[image: JSON]

The expression in the second step is ...

```
json(variables('Array As Text'))
```

Naturally, it can all be performed in one step though, like thus ...

```
json(outputs('HTTP')['headers']['ip'])
```

Given what you've provided, translating that to your flow is something you'll need to take care of.

**Result**

[image: Result]